# Пропадание изображение в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, firebase-android

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Имеется "чат",в котором пользователь может прикрепить фото к сообщению из галереи, которые в последствии отображаются в чате. Фото я никак не сжимаю,в оригинале отправляю в FireBase storage,и от туда же и выгружаю. Пока не разобрался как это сделать грамотно. Проблема видна на видео( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZC4aBFOm5nc ) , картинки появляются и сразу исчезают.
вот так я загружаю фото в imageview

```
public void setIsShowImgChat(FirechatMsgViewHolder firechatMsgViewHolder,
                                 ChatMessage chatMessage, StorageReference reference, Context context) {

        if (chatMessage.getMsgPhotoUrl() != null) {

            Glide.with(context /* context */)
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(reference.child("image/" + chatMessage.getMsgPhotoUrl()))
                    .into(mMsgImage);
            mMsgImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Вас эта строка не смущает? `mMsgImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: Ну я если сообщение не содержит изображение,скрываю imageview,и отображаю соответственно

Comment: Нет, в данном случае вы просто прячете `ImageView` когда находите прикреплённое фото

Comment: ну я и мега мозг. Да,на самом деле так и есть,сам запутался в своей логике. А есть какой-то грамотный способ закешировать фото,что бы они при прокрутке не исчезали?